# Processing 'Search' in an Arraylist

Tags: search, arraylist, processing

I'm stuck with the following problem within Processing for a school assignment.

I'm using a dataset in a tab seperated format, This is being read and parsed to my Activity class. The (menuAnswer, "Subagency") is used so I only get the data I need.

```js
  for(TableRow singleRow : trafficTable.findRows(menuAnswer, "SubAgency")){
     Activity singleActivity = new Activity();
     singleActivity.parseRow(singleRow);
     activities.add(singleActivity);
  }
```

The Activity class looks this:

```js
class Activity{

String violationType;
String subAgency;
String race;
String gender; 
Date readDate;

  void parseRow(TableRow row){ 
    this.subAgency = row.getString("SubAgency");
    this.violationType = row.getString("Violation Type");
    this.race = row.getString("Race");
    this.gender = row.getString("Gender");
    
    this.readDate = parseDate(row.getString("Time Of Stop") + " " + row.getString("Date"), "HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy");
  }
  
   void printInfo(){ 
     println(subAgency + " / " + race + " / " + readDate + " / " + violationType);

   }
}
```

Every (usefull) piece of my dataset is inserted into an variable.

In my main class I want to search in the violationType String and count the ammount of "Warning"s within this String. I use the following code, which is not working:

```js
  for (Activity singleActivity : activities)
    if(singleActivity.violationType == "Warning"){
      warningCount++;
      println("is it working?");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Mello

Answer (score 0):

After searching I found my answer:

```js
  for (Activity singleActivity : activities)
    if(singleActivity.violationType == "Warning"){
      warningCount++;
      println("is it working?");
    }
```

My notation of my If statement is wrong and should be with .equals instead of == operator, like this:

```js
void countWarning(){
for (Activity singleActivity : activities){  
 if(singleActivity.violationType.equals("Warning")){
  warningCount++;
 }
}
}
```